# r - how to select a different number of observation within each group

Tags: r, data-management

I am relatively new to r (coming from sas) 
I need to select a different number of observations within each group. Groups are identified by the values of two variables

```
ToSelect <- data.frame(
                           key1=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                           key2=c("a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","b"),
                           var1=c(2,3,4,6,2,7,8,5,7,1,8,5)
                          )
NumObs <- data.frame(
                           key1=c(1,1,2,2),
                           key2=c("a","b","a","b"),
                           NumObs=c(1,2,2,1)
                       )
```

I tried (from question "Select first 80 observations for each level in R")

```
ToSelect <- merge(x=ToSelect,y=NumObs,by=c("key1","key2"))
library(plyr)
Selected <- ddply(ToSelect, .(key1,key2), head, n = NumObs)
```

which gives

> Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE

which is probably an obvious error to experts (n a scalar, NumObs a vector?)

From the same question, I tried:

```
Selected <- do.call(
                     rbind, 
                     lapply(split(ToSelect, c(ToSelect$key1,ToSelect$key2)), head, NumObs)
                    )
```

which gives

> Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE. 
>   In addition: Warning message: In
>   split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :   data
>   length is not a multiple of split variable

So, same error as before, plus the multiple stuff, I cannot use split if groups have different length?

Then I found the question "Observation number by group" and I couldn't make the rle/sequence answer work in my case but adapting the ddply answer:

```
ToSelect <- ddply(ToSelect, .(key1, key2), function(z){
                                                         cbind(var1=z$var1,NumObs=z$NumObs,
                                                         data.frame(
                                                                       SeqNum = seq_along(z$key2)
                                                                    )
                                                               )
                                                       }
                 )
Selected <- ToSelect[ToSelect$SeqNum<=ToSelect$NumObs,c("key1","key2","var1")]
```

which works.

Obviously my real data is much bigger, so is there an alternative and better way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for efficiency, might I suggest looking into the `data.table` package.  A fairly straight-forward solution to this problem could be:

```
#Convert objects to data.table
require("data.table")
ToSelect <- data.table(ToSelect)
NumObs <- data.table(NumObs)

#Merge data
ToSelect <- merge(ToSelect,NumObs,by=c("key1","key2"),all.x=T)

#Provide intra-group ordering variable
ToSelect[,Grp.Seq:=seq(1:.N),by=c("key1","key2")]
Selected <- ToSelect[NumObs>=Grp.Seq]
Selected

   key1 key2 var1 NumObs Grp.Seq
1:    1    a    2      1       1
2:    1    b    4      2       1
3:    1    b    6      2       2
4:    2    a    7      2       1
5:    2    a    8      2       2
6:    2    b    1      1       1
```

If you are new to `R` anyway, and you often work with large datasets, it might make sense to learn `data.table` from the beginning.  I work with very large datasets for my work, and the data.frame class is not really practical for much of the work I do.  It is very easy to switch back between `data.frame` and `data.table` if need be.

Comment: For the time being the dplyr answer works but I will certainly look into data.table, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do, then `data.table` will be immensely helpful. This little one liner basically randomly samples the values of `var1` by group, according to the desired number of observations giving in your `NumObs` table. Try:

```
# Load package
require(data.table)
# Make your data.frames into data.tables                       
ts <- data.table( ToSelect , key = c( "key1","key2"))
no <- data.table( NumObs , key = c( "key1","key2") )

# Join together based on key columns and sample by group
no[ts][ , sample( var1 , NumObs , TRUE ) , by = c("key1","key2") ]
#   key1 key2 V1
#1:    1    a  2 
#2:    1    b  6 #|_ Two observations of group 1b
#3:    1    b  6 #|
#4:    2    a  5 #|_ Two observations of group 2a
#5:    2    a  8 #|
#6:    2    b  5
```

If you don't want to sample with replacement (as above, look at the values for group 1b - they are the same) then remove the `TRUE` argument of `sample` (so you cannot select more observations than the total number of observations in each group).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with which you can select n numbers of observations from `ToSelect` per group of `key1` and `key2`-pair. n in this case is specified by `NumObs` in `NumObs` data.frame.

To do this I use the package `dplyr` but there are certainly other ways of doing the same thing.

Install the package and load it into your library:

```
require(dplyr)
```

I first join (=merge) both data.frames together:

```
df <- left_join(ToSelect, NumObs, by=c("key1", "key2"))
```

Then I group the resulting data.frame df by `key1` and `key2` and select the first `NumObs` numbers of oberservations per group:

```
df <- df %.% group_by(key1, key2) %.% filter(1:n() <= NumObs)

>df
#  key1 key2 var1 NumObs
#1    1    a    2      1
#2    1    b    4      2
#3    1    b    6      2
#4    2    a    7      2
#5    2    a    8      2
#6    2    b    1      1
```

If you want the resulting data.frame without the `NumObs` column, you can adapt it to:

```
df <- df %.% group_by(key1, key2) %.% filter(1:n() <= NumObs) %.% select(-NumObs)
```